# How to limit access to a database (or a document within a database) based on invitation

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

From what i've been able to discern so far, Firebase/Firestore seem like the perfect platform to use for an app I am writing.  However I can't quite connect all the dots when trying to design my backend.  I am hoping that someone will be able to give answer a couple of basic questions about the use of FB/FS.

With my app, a user will be able to share a small piece of data with a select group of friends.  ie if the data is to be a To-Do list, the user would create the list on his device (iphone only) and then invite a small group of friends (probably less than 10) to share that data.  The friends would have read-only access by default, however, the user can assign any number of them to be "admins" which would allow them read/write permission. When any changes occur to the data, all "friends" who have access to the data will be notified  (by some means - push notifications etc). They can manually sync or setup the app to automatically sync.  It seems like FB/FS can be used for this right out of the box.  However there are a couple of concepts that I can't get my head around.

The database I setup is accessible by ALL users of my app by default.  It's not clear (at least to me) how I would set it up so when a user creates (in this case) a to-do list and invites 5 friends, only those 5 friends can access or even know about that data.  This is main stumbling block in my development path.

Regarding invitations.  I read in the FB/FS documentation that invitations and notifications are among the many features available.  I'm not clear on how this will work if a) the recipient doesn't have my app installed and b) how the inviter would get feedback when the invitation was accepted or declined.

Any guidance that anyone is willing to share to help me get started will be a huge help and will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new privates collections inside the main collection, and set different rules for access.

Check at: [Firebase Firestore get private fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51373102/firebase-firestore-get-private-fields)